# DDD repositories, and REST

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Should DDD Repository always return aggregate and all it's value objects and entities?

For an example, I have Invoice object which has it's type and items.

```
Invoice
  --Id
  --Issuer
  --InvoiceType
  --Items
```

Data are persisted in 4 SQL Tables.

```
Invoices (FK to invoice type, FK to issuers),
InvoiceTypes
Items(fk to Invoice)
Issuers
```

If a repository should always return aggregates in it's full state, is it a bit of overkill to include InvoiceType and Items if i need to fetch 50 invoices, and display only ID and IssuerName.

Example for

```
InvoiceRepository
{
  //should this also fetch InvoiceTypes and items from SQL, or i need separate invoice model for this
  public List<Invoice> FetchForListing(int page, int take);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should DDD Repository always return aggregate and all it's value objects and entities?

No.  In use cases where you are going to be performing a write, you should load everything, because you need the full internal state to ensure that your change satisfies the invariant.

But if you are only going to perform a *read*, the full state isn't necessary at all -- it's reasonable to limit to the data you pull out.

(For example: when using the [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs) pattern, reads tend to not touch the aggregate at all, but instead copy data from "projections" of aggregate state into a more suitable representation.)

```
InvoiceRepository
{
    // should this also fetch InvoiceTypes and items from SQL, 
    // or i need separate invoice model for this
    public List<Invoice> FetchForListing(int page, int take);
}
```

So in this case, you wouldn't return a `List<Invoice>`, since that isn't what you want, and you might not use the same interface to represent the repository

```
InvoiceSummaryRepository
{
    public List<InvoiceSummary> readSummary(int page, int take);
}
```

Check in your own ubiquitous language to figure out what `InvoiceSummary` is actually called, to determine whether `List<InvoiceSummary>` is actually a thing with a name of its own (likely is you are using it to build the representation of a resource in your REST api), and so on.

Comment: oh i see. I understood wrongly about repositories being tied to aggregates. I was in a belief that i always have to return Invoice Domain object, but in fact it can be any representation by business requires. What is InvoiceSummary in this case? Domain model, entity, value object?

Comment: InvoiceSummary here is just a read model over your data / a query - there's no business rules involved, so I wouldn't worry about trying to apply DDD names to it

Comment: Technically, it is probably a value object - this is a read use case, so the data should be immutable.  I agree with @tomliversidge that it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: The answer is technically correct.  However, consider making the naming somewhat more explicit.  A `Repository` *should* ideally be concerned with aggregates.  You could name the read bit something like `InvoiceQuery`.  It could return any useful data representation and should never be concerned with aggregates.  You could return integers for counts, DTOs (as in the answer), or even a `dynamic` or `DataRow` in the .Net world.  But yes, the two concepts should ideally be split.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. @VoiceOfUnreason i owe you a beer. You are answeing all my questions lately :)

Comment: I agree with @EbenRoux in avoiding to overload the `Repository` concept. When applying CQRS principles, a repository should only returns aggregate roots, not query DTOs.